# Why can Android API 19 use the functions added by API 23

Tags: android, seekbar

I'm reading source code of some view. I noticed that Android API 19 use the functions added by API 23. Why is that?I'm confused.
Such as:

```
Drawable#setLayoutDirection
```

In google'doc,it should be added in API23. However,I had seen it in API 19.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android has compatibility libraries like Android Support Library and AndroidX that back-port new features to old versions of Android.

Every time Google makes a new framework feature, they'll add it into that particular framework API. But they'll also try to support it as far back as they can through these compatibility libraries.

So, in the example of `Drawable#setLayoutDirection`, that method will be called directly from the Android framework on a device that's API 23+, but it'll be called from the compatibility library if the device is lower than API 23.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's helpful for me. And I think I need to learn more about how does the compatibility library work.